# How to validate password and confirm password field in Accelerated Mobile Pages (AMP)?

Tags: amp-html

In amp-form POST method., how to validate password and confirm password field?

And also how to validate already exist username and email ID and show error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AMP doesn't allow client side JS/JQuery, so you have to do server side validation after the form submission.

Answer (score 0):

> Not Allowed in AMP

```
<input type=password>
<input type=button>
<input type=file>
<input type=image>
```

Please refer : [**amp-form**](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/dynamic/amp-form)